# Does allocating objects of the same size improve GC or "new" performance?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, new-operator

Suppose we have to create many small objects of byte array type. The size varies but it always below 1024 bytes , say 780,256,953....

Will it improve operator new or GC efficiency over time if we always allocate only bytes[1024], and use only space needed?

UPD: This is short living objects, created for parsing binary protocol messages.

UPD: The number of the objects is the same in both cases, it just the size of allocation which changes (random vs. always 1024).

In C++ it would matter because of fragmentation and C++ new performance. But in C#....

Comment: Have you profiled it to see for yourself?

Comment: Nope, I was hoping for fast answer, also it demands profiling systems for prolonged time.

Comment: Since the objects are "short living objects, created for parsing binary protocol messages" would you consider using unsafe code and `stackalloc`?  It seems that this is exactly what it's intended for: short-term allocation of smallish arrays in a situation where high performance is desired.

Comment: There's no free lunch when it comes to optimization. Profiling is the name of the game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will it improve operator new or GC efficiency over time if we always allocate only bytes[1024], and use only space needed?

Maybe. You're going to have to profile it and see.

The way we allocate syntax tree nodes inside the Roslyn compiler is quite interesting, and I'm eventually going to do a blog post about it. Until then, the relevant bit to your question is this interesting bit of trivia. Our allocation pattern typically involves allocating an "underlying" immutable node (which we call the "green" node) and a "facade" mutable node that wraps it (which we call the "red" node). As you might imagine, it is frequently the case that we end up allocating these in pairs: green, red, green, red, green, red.

The green nodes are persistent and therefore long-lived; the facades are short-lived, because they are discarded on every edit. Therefore it is frequently the case that the garbage collector has green / hole / green / hole / green / hole, and then the green nodes move up a generation.

Our assumption had always been that making data structures smaller will always improve GC performance. Smaller structures equals less memory allocated, equals less collection pressure, equals fewer collections, equals more performance, right? But we discovered through profiling that making the red nodes *smaller* in this scenario actually *decreases* GC performance. **Something about the particular size of the holes affects the GC in some odd way**; not being an expert on the internals of the garbage collector, it is opaque to me why that should be.

So is it possible that changing the size of your allocations can affect the GC in some unforseen way? **Yes, it is possible.** But, first off, it is **unlikely**, and second it is *impossible to know whether you are in that situation until you actually try it in real-world scenarios and carefully measure GC performance*.

And of course, you might not be gated on GC performance. Roslyn does so many small allocations that it is crucial that we tune our GC-impacting behaviour, but we do an *insane* number of small allocations. The vast majority of .NET programs do not stress the GC the way we do. If you are in the minority of programs that stress the GC in interesting ways then there is no way around it; you're going to have to profile and gather empirical data, just like we do on the Roslyn team.

If you are not in that minority, then don't worry about GC performance; you probably have a bigger problem somewhere else that you should be dealing with first.

Comment: Could you ask the team that handles GC why would this happen? I would really like to hear an answer from someone who is an expert on the internals of the GC. Mostly because this behavior doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

`new` is fast, it is the GC that causes problems. So, it depends on how long your arrays live for.

If they only live a short time, I don't think there will be any improvement from allocating 1024 byte arrays. In fact this will put more pressure on the GC because of the wasted space and will probably degrade performance.

If they live for the life of your application, I would consider allocating one large array and using chunks of it for each small array. You would need to profile this to see if it helps.

Comment: Good point about life time of allocations, but keyword here is definitely 'profile' :)

Comment: I cannot see how it puts more pressure on GC. The number of allocated object is the same...

Comment: @Boris The objects will be allocated in the Gen-0 heap, which has a certain capacity. GCs are run when the heap gets full, so the more space you allocate, the sooner the heap gets full and the sooner a GC is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, Allocating or clearing a bytes array requires only one instruction, regardless of its size. (I speak about your case. there are exceptions)

You shouldn't worry about the performance aspect of garbage collection, unless you are sure that it's a bottleneck for your application (ie you create a lot of references with complex relationship, and throw it shortly afterward... And the garbage collection is noticeable.)

To read an excellent story about a well known (and quite useful) site having performance issues with the .NET GC (in an impressive use case) see this blog. http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector ;)

But the most important thing about GC is: Never, ever do optimisations before being sure that you have a problem. Because if you do, you will probably have one. Applications are complex, and the GC interacts with every parts of it, at runtime. Apart from simple cases, predicting its behavior and bottlenecks beforehand seems (in my opinion) difficult.

Comment: Famous last words: "you shouldn't worry about performance". You know, there is a **huge** difference between saying that it's hard to predict bottlenecks (which is true), and that you should therefore focus on optimizing the ones that appear, and then saying that you *must never ever* even *think* about optimization until it's too late

Comment: +1 I do think that the advice is pretty solid and -1 is not ok in my opinion

Comment: Are you sure that there are times when you should torture yourself with GC optimisation before even knowing your bottlenecks? OK I agree, you shouldn't do anything stupid in your code, and you should know how the GC operates to make sensible algorithm choices. But the sort of optimisations stackoverflow used to speed things up (in the link I provided) really shouldn't considered beforehand: They solve an issue, but are rather strange patterns. Don't forget I didn't spoke generally. I spoke about GC optimization. OK I am editing it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also don't think only allocating 1024 byte arrays will improve the GC.
Since the GC is *not* determistic, I also think it will not be your problem.

You can influence the GC by using `using {}` statements arround your arrays to free memory (maybe) sooner.

Comment: The `using` statement will not affect GC at all.

Comment: after the `using {}` is exited the pointers to anything in it will be removed, therefore the GC will cleanup any resources which no other pointer points to (from objects or methods outside the `using {}`)

Comment: Not necessarily.  The only guarantees after the `using` block exits are that (1) the object's `Dispose()` method has been called, and (2) the *local variable* is no longer in scope.  It is perfectly legal to do something like `using(var foo = new MyDisposableObject()) { SomeOtherObject.StaticListOfObjects.Append(foo); }` and then `foo` will definitely not get GC'd any earlier.  The GC has no knowledge of C# scope: an object will not necessarily get GC'd when its last reference goes out of scope, and will not necessarily *not* get  GC'd while references to it are still in scope!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think GC will be the problem and/ or bottleneck.

Allocating objects of different sizes and freeing them in a different sequence can lead to fragmented heap memory. So this is where allocating objects of the same size might come in handy.

If you really do allocate/ free a lot and really do see this as your bottleneck, try to re-use the objects with a local object cache. This can lead to performance increase, especially if they are data-only objects that do not implement a lot of logic. If the objects do implement a lot of logic and require mor complex initialisation (RAII-pattern) I would forego the performance increase for robustness of the program...

hth

Mario